# Loading / inserting images after page has loaded / scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to load images onto the page after it has loaded.

The best (but crude) way to demonstrate this is:

```
<div id="images">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            document.write("<img src=\"imgs/"+i+".jpg\" \">");
        }
    </script>
</div>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alexjamesbrown/XPBdg/

... Yes, loading 10000  tags onto the page!

What I'd like to happen is the page load, then the 'for' loop fires after the page has loaded, one after the other (as not to disrupt the browser too much)

I also tried this in jQuery, but it literally hung the browser...

```
$(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        $('#images').append('<img src=\"img/'+i+'.jpg\" width: 20px; height: 20px;\ class=\"img\">')
    }
})
```

So, a bit like a simple version of the 'infinate scroll' type apps: http://www.innovativephp.com/demo/infinitescroll/

using a for loop, instead of retrieving data from the server....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load each image one at a time try

```
var imageCount = 0;

function nextImage( ) {
    var img = new Image(); // create image element
    img.src = "http://lorempixel.com/40/40" + imageCount; // use imageCount to change image
    img.onload = function( ) { 

        if( imageCount <= 10000 ) {

            imageCount++;
            var imgElement = document.getElementById("images");
            imgElement.appendChild( img );
            nextImage(); // only once image has loaded should we try to load another
        }
    }
}

nextImage();​
```

Just got it working. Have a look at the fiddle [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/XPBdg/1/)

By the way you could delay loading further by using something like

```
setTimeout( nextImage, 100 );
```

Comment: Could you flesh this out a bit with html... not sure what Image() is?

Comment: @alexjamesbrown have a look at the fiddle and also updated my example.

Comment: Yeah, this is along the right lines... just seems a little bit 'clunky' (i know you said it would be...!) just wonder if there's a way to load them a little smoother? maybe 5 at a time or something would make it a bit quicker?

Comment: Here's an even better example of pretty much exactly what i'm trying to achieve http://cssline.com/

Comment: Maybe you should look at something like [**infinite scroll**](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Loading 10.000 img elements in a single request wont be a good practice. You would think about to change the logic.

Anyway, you can try something like following to increase performance.

```
<div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var elems = [], limit = 5000;
            while(limit--) {
                elems.push('<img src="http://lorempixel.com/40/40" />');
            }
            document.write( elems.join(' ') );
            // or using jquery : $('body').append( elems.join(' ') );
        </script>
</div>​​​​​​​​
```

Touching to DOM in every single loop iteration greatly decreases the performance.

Comment: How's this different to my example?

Comment: Not different. Simply it does same thing faster while less distributing the browser.